# Python multithreading with pypubsub and wx

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, wxpython, pypubsub

I have a program that is structured like this:

[image]

The `GUI` is made with wxPython and is in the Main Thread. After launching the application, the GUI thread creates `Thread1`, which creates a static class `Class1`, which creates `Thread2`.

Thread1 talks with the GUI using `wx.PostEvent`, and everything works fine. I need Thread1 to communicate also with Thread2, so I decided to do that using pyPubSub. Thread2 needs to work in the background because it contains some operations that are executed periodically, but it contains also a function (let's say `my_func()`) that Thread1 needs to call on certain events. I decided to put `my_func()` in Thread2 because I don't want it to stop the execution of Thread1, but that's exactly what happens: in Thread1 after some events I use `pub.sendMessage("events", message="Hello")` to trigger `my_func()`; Thread2 is structured like this:

```
class Thread2(Thread)
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        pub.subscribe(self.my_func, "events")
    
    def run(self):
        while True:
        # do stuff
    
    def my_func(self, message):
        # do other stuff using the message
        # call parent functions
```

The parent of Thread2 is Class1, so when I create the thread in Class1 I do:

```
self.t2 = Thread2(self)
self.t2.start()
```

Why does Thread2 stops the execution of Thread1?

Comment: Without knowing the specifics of your threads/functions, thread1 is performing a function and needs it to finish, before moving on. So, it doesn't matter `where` the function is, it still has to wait for it to complete. Unless you know different, in which case we need more detail.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony  shouldn't events allow to continue without waiting? If it's not like that, I could have simply called `t2.my_func()` from Thread1

Comment: `a function (let's say my_func()) that Thread1 needs to call on certain events.` The operative word in that quote is `call`. If that's not what you meant, then we need more detail. What is this function, what does it do? Context!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put in different words what was said in the comments, pypubsub's `sendMessage` is actually **calling** your listener function and thus waits for it to return before moving on. If this listener function takes a significant amount of time to run, then the behavior you obtain is an apparent "blocking" of your thread.

Here you probably want to 'send' a lightweight message to trigger the computation and 'listen' to the result in another place, in a 'non-blocking' fashion.